# How can I get rid of `Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location` when using INSERT in MFC ODBC Database.ExecuteSQL(`...`)

Tags: c++, mfc, ms-access-2010

My task is to access an Access-Database-File *.accdb with C/C++.

I want to insert Statusmessages from a C/C++ based Application. My choice fell to MFC ODBC. I am pretty new on programming C. I read very much about this topic and tried to get to work many examples. I only have Office-2010 x64, thatwhy I have to compile as x64 to get the Access-connection working. I have Windows 10 Professional running. This is Visual Studio 2015.

- I already gave `everybody` the needed permission to Tempfolder %TEMP% (resolves error).
- I already gave `everybody` permission to (Regedit) HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/OBDC and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/OBDC to resolve some Registry-Permission-Error.

I tried very hard on getting everything working as it should, but I got stuck on implementing any INSERT SQL-Query without causing this error:
`Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location`
The weired thing: This Insert is working.

DELETE works without any Error.
SELECT works without any Error.
INSERT works but throws some silent Error in the `Immediate Window`.

```
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(616) : AppMsg - Warning: ODBC Success With Info, 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(174) : AppMsg - Fehler bei SQLSetConnectAttr-Aufruf für Treiber
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(174) : AppMsg - State:IM006,Native:0,Origin:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(954) : AppMsg - DBMS: ACCESS
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(958) : AppMsg - Version: 12.00.0000
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\dbcore.cpp(964) : AppMsg - ODBC Driver Manager Version: 03.80.0000
```

On Line: db.ExecuteSQL(sql);

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8B941A1C8 in WriterConsole.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0000000EC137E508.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8B941A1C8 in WriterConsole.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0000000EC137E508.
```

On Line: db.ExecuteSQL(queryinsert);

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8B941A1C8 in WriterConsole.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0000000EC137E5F8.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8B941A1C8 in WriterConsole.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: int at memory location 0x0000000EC137E5F8.
```

Here is a screen of my Code:

[image: CodeScreenshot]

(I cannot use SQLite, which I would prefer here.)
I am sorry to ask you all, but I do not seem to be able to figure it out by my own. I have problems to understand what this Error means, how I can possibly resolve it or if I can ignore it. Thank you for your time.

**EDIT: Here is the Project-Folder zipped.** http://cloud.downfight.de/index.php/s/mkuxZi7uFmnQFub note that the database has to be at the folderlocation which has to be inserted within const LPCTSTR DBAuth

Comment: I already tried to not use öäüÖÄÜßÉ chars within Insert. It works but the Error stays.

Comment: It's probably and error with your SQL syntax (which is difficult to read from your image).

Comment: I cannot see one: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tgml.png You can click on the Image to load it larger.

Comment: There's a missing semicolon on the end of that first INSERT statement, which may or may not be causing some issue. I'm not up to date with what Access requires, but it's worth correcting anyway. Also, you can copy the formatted string from the debug window and paste into Access to manually check if there's a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you @RogerRowland, but the problem persists. I took a snipped out of my screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/yDCtCD7.png Those two make some insert. The insert is made and ok! But they both fail, nevertheless of the ; , the special german chars, the different type of string... There seems to be a error and everything is working. Does anybody know I can ignore such errors? Maybe they are some internal info only, catched and processed within the class?

Comment: I now added my zipped Project Folder.